# is it ever sensible to use WCF concurrency combination InstanceContextMode=Single and ConcurrencyMode=Multiple?

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf

If I've understood correctly you should implement locking to prevent concurrency issues and thus lose all the benefits of multithreading.

Article below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and#Instance%20mode%20=%20Single%20and%20Concurrency%20=%20Multiple

describes this with example. However I cannot understand how this works, since there's no locking.

Thanks & Best regards - Matti

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about the article you reference is that it draws its conclusions from using a Console host. While that article may be accurate for Console hosted services or may even apply to a Windows Service host, I'd be very leary of carrying over some of those assumptions/conclusions into WCF services hosted by IIS/[WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx). With a IIS/WAS based host, there is rarely justification for using InstanceContextMode Single (basically your singleton pattern).

Comment: thanks for your answer. i don't quite undesrtand why it would work for console. isn't only incrementing (i++) instance variable a possible concurrency issue if thread 1 reads the and value increments it, and thread 2 is scheduled in before thread 1 writing it back. then the increment of thread 2 would be lost.

Comment: It's not that code isn't applicable, it's just the multi-threaded environment in IIS is more complex and the assumptions drived from the performance of a Console host may not be valid. There may be multiple ServiceHost instances for a given service type in IIS which isn't normally the case in Console or Windows Service hosting. In an IIS hosted environment, a multi-threaded singleton instance of a service will not give you better scalability than per-call instantiation and ConcurrencyMode = Single since it is IIS/WAS that's handling the request load.

Comment: ok. i understand, but can you tell me why the scenario described in my comment (thread 2's increment is lost) can't happen.

Answer (score 2):

Concurrency issues generally only arise when you have to deal with changing state. If you were creating a web service which simply served data and was not responsible for handling state changes then this configuration could be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Locking doesn't cause you to "lose all the benefits of multithreading".

If you write your code like this:

```cs
lock (shared_object) 
{
    // do everything here
    return value;
}
```

then yes, you've just caused a concurrent app to become synchronous (and wasted threads that are waiting on the lock). But you don't have to write code that way to make it thread-safe.

Generally, there are only a few critical sections that actually require locking. In your linked article, for example, "i" is the only shared variable, so all that would be needed to make it thread safe would be to use `var local_i = Interlocked.Increment(ref i);`.

This is a trivial example, though, so of course it *looks* like you don't gain anything. In a real world scenario you'd be doing things that didn't need synchronization and would gain benefits from being concurrent.